# Designing data ware house from oltp database

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, data-warehouse

**Problem** We have to design data ware house for the data base.

**information available**: We have an oltp database dump .

**Question**  Before designing ware house what all thing we should be knowing ?

what all question we should ask from oltp Database owner and business (user of DWH).

Could please any one can help on that .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I can think of right now, not neccessarily best order or exhaustive list:

- First I would get a clear picture what questions are ought to be asked.
- Then I would ask how "fresh" the data has to be.
- Then who will be using it in what cases.
- Then what reports or adhoc or self service stuff is required.
- Then how metadata (server load, job performance, failovers) will be monitored
- Then if there is a specific required modelling technique
- Then if there will be tools which need to get data
- Then if the data will be updated
- Then if other sources need to be included in the future
- Then how much data will be processed at any time
- Then how the data model is looking like

And then I think I would have enough information to capture the general size of the project and possible problems which can be tackled beforehand.